# Sidebar overlapping header despite using background-images and Z-Index

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hope someone has an easy answer on this.  I have a header image which is just a 75px high gradient with a fade on the bottom.  I have it set as the background image on my header  and I want to throw in a left-sidebar on my page.  There is a transparency on the header image and when I have my sidebar  I can't get it to sit behind the header.  You can see in this screenshot:

[image: sidebar]

The green sidebar won't "sit" behind the header.  I have the header z-index set to 99 and the sidebar to 1.  I tried the reverse to make sure I didn't mix up my numbers but that didn't work. Both are absolutely positioned.  I'm attaching their CSS selectors in the hopes someone has an easy answer.  Am sure I'm missing something basic:

```
div.header {
 z-index: 99;
 background: transparent;
 background-image: url(images/header_bg.png);
 position: absolute;
 height: 85px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

div#leftsidebar {
 height: 400px;
 border-right-style: dashed;
 border-right-width: 1px;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-top: 75px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #66ff66;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should work if the two elements being styled are siblings in the HTML, not sure otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the answer was, and none of you guys would have known this, that my sidebar  was inside the header  and obviously it couldn't sit behind its parent 's background.  Makes sense.  I wouldn't have done it on purpose but think that when I was writing the HTML I pushed the header  tag way down and didn't realize that I was writing my sidebar inside of it.  Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "background:transparent;" attribute from your div.header selector.

Comment: Jeff, that doesn't work.  I only added that attribute because I was stabbing at ideas after seeing it elsewhere.  Thanks for trying.